# when should we use es6 format to create a component without useing props in react Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

which way is the right way to write a component that does not pass into with props?  like `const xxxx = (yyyy)` (from es6?)  or `const xxxx: FC = () => {yyy}` ?

from my example, i guess for `CompA` using as FC is more suitable because it use the props from `Home`?
what about `CompB`, `CompC`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { FC } from "react";

const Home = (props: { caseType: string }) => {
  const { caseType } = props;

  const CompA: FC = () => {
    return (
      <div className="1">
        <a href="google.com">google---{caseType}</a>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const CompB: FC = () => {
    return (
      <div className="2">
        <a href="amazon.com">amazon</a>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const compC = (
    <span className="3">
      <a href="tesla.com">num tesla</a>{" "}
    </span>
  );

  return caseType === "1" ? <CompA /> : caseType === "2" ? <CompB /> : compC;
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <Home caseType="3" />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and commonly used way to described the props being passed to your functional components is:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { FC } from "react";


// define your Props
type HomeProps = {
caseType: string
}

const Home: FC<HomeProps> = ({ caseType }) => {

  console.log({ caseType }) // will be the prop you have with the caseType property of type "string"
```

Here are some examples:
https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/

If you are unfamiliar with TS generics, here is a link to the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: my question is what format I should use for `CompA`, `CompB`, `CompC` under my example code

Comment: All of these formats will work and I don't really see any differences between A and B. I personally like to explicitly state that I'm dealing with a Functional Component.